# How do you use php Session when you navigate via an html link?

Tags: php, html, session

I have used session which works on my first page but when I click a link to go to another page it doesn't work. here is a section of the code for the first page:

```
<a href = "preferences.php">Preferences</a></div>

<?php $uname = $_SESSION['uname1']; $_SESSION['uname1'] = $uname; echo ($uname . "fanta");?>
```

This prints out that session is fine.
Here is a section of the preferences.php, the second page:

```
</form>

<?php $uname = $_SESSION['uname1']; $_SESSION['uname1'] = $uname; echo ($uname . "fanta");?>
```

This time it prints only "fanta" the session is not working.

Comment: Did you start the session on both pages? You need to have one 
[`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) on every page which uses sessions.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$_SESSION['uname1'] = $uname;`?  You *just* assigned `$uname = $_SESSION['uname1'];` on the previous statement.

Comment: @Namachuru Mpachone can you add more code and session is a global variable you can access it unless you include the `session_start` and create a `$_SESSION['login]` array.

Comment: I didn't use session_start() yet it works for the first page, why doesn't work for the second page?

Comment: You are probably starting the session somewhere on page 1 (e.g. in an included page) but not on page 2. Therefore, the variable is not set on page 2. Here are some infos: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot. The problem was that I was not using session_start(). It now fully works.